# Connect to MongoDB on Appfog from localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb, remote-access, appfog

I'm trying to run my application on my local pc. Everything looks perfectly fine on the cloud, it works and connects to MongoDB with the code below:

```
    $services_json = json_decode(getenv("VCAP_SERVICES"),true);
$mongo_config = $services_json["mongodb-1.8"][0]["credentials"];

// Generally will be localhost if you're querying from the machine that Mongo is installed on
$config['mongo_host'] = $mongo_config["hostname"];

// Generally will be 27017 unless you've configured Mongo otherwise
$config['mongo_port'] = $mongo_config["port"];

// The database you want to work from (required)
$config['mongo_db'] = $mongo_config["db"];

// Leave blank if Mongo is not running in auth mode
$config['mongo_user'] = $mongo_config["username"];
$config['mongo_pass'] = $mongo_config["password"];
```

But since I cannot get the vcap_services from my local pc, I'm using constant values for the connection to connect my app to the remote mongo server on appfog:

```
    // Generally will be localhost if you're querying from the machine that Mongo is installed on
$config['mongo_host'] = "***";

// Generally will be 27017 unless you've configured Mongo otherwise
$config['mongo_port'] = "***";

// The database you want to work from (required)
$config['mongo_db'] = "db";

// Leave blank if Mongo is not running in auth mode
$config['mongo_user'] = "***";
$config['mongo_pass'] = "***";
```

But when I try to execute the app through `http://localhost/my-app`, it gave me this error:

```
Unable to connect to MongoDB: Failed to connect to: ***: Connection timed out
```

What can be the problem?

*** values are deleted for the privacy.

Comment: And are you able to connect to`http://localhost:28017/`?

Comment: Yes, but the main problem is not about localhost. I have another host like 10.*.*.* that I need to connect on appfog from local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try connecting without the VCAP variables not on localhost but the actual server? AppFog may not give authorization to connect without VCAP variables or something may be wrong on the values you manually get.

I believe this is an authorization problem. Try another cloud service if you cannot handle with it. This is not the only solution.

Comment: Already changed the service I'm using. AppFog would not like to help me but I think you may be right. The service I'm using gives me the exact values, not from a VCAP service.